# Implementing a Search Bar Under a Tab in Ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am having an issue with adding a search bar under the "Search" tab of my project. I use similar logic to how [this](http://codepen.io/brandyshea/pen/gbZrNQ) is laid out, but it does not work properly in the `ionic serve --lab` live in-browser preview. The search bar ends up not wide enough and halfway down the list that it is meant to be filtering.

When I place the code for the search bar directly outside the `<ion-view>` tag in the html file, it doesn't show up. When I put it directly inside the `<ion-content>` tag, it looks wrong. Any tips on how I might want to implement this?

Here is the code for the search bar I am using:

```
<ion-header-bar class="bar-light bar-subheader">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Filter contacts..." ng-model="search" ng-focus="searchFocused = true" ng-blur="searchFocused = false" ng-change="scrollTop()" class="full-width">
    <button ng-if="search.length" class="button button-icon ion-android-close input-button" ng-click="clearSearch()">
      </button>
  </ion-header-bar>
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle for this?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/12scby2d/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you put `bar` class with `sub-header` your search bar issue should fix.
Checkout here -

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.clearSearch = function() {
    $scope.search = '';
  };
});
```

```css
.button.button-icon.input-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 5px;
  color: #bbb;
}

.item img {
  height: 60px;
  width: 60px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.my-item.item {
  padding-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.1.0/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Header</h1>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-subheader">
    <input type="search"
           placeholder="Filter contacts..."
           ng-model="search"
           ng-focus="searchFocused = true"
           ng-blur="searchFocused = false"
           ng-change="scrollTop()"
           class="full-width">
    <button ng-if="search.length"
            class="button button-icon ion-android-close input-button"
            ng-click="clearSearch()">
    </button>
  </ion-header-bar>
  <ion-content>
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item class="my-item">item 1</ion-item>
      <ion-item class="my-item">item 2</ion-item>
      <ion-item class="my-item">item 3</ion-item>
      <ion-item class="my-item">item 4</ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</body>
```

Comment: Hm... the search bar shows (only for iPhone version), but 1)the content has disappeared 2)The "X" button is still in the middle of the screen